# Optimality of Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

In the method of Lagrange Multipliers we want to maximize $f(x,y)$ constrained to a level curve, i.e $g(x,y) = 0$. To do so we define the Lagrangian function 
$$L(x,y) = f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y)$$
It makes sense that the critical points of $L$ are when $\nabla f = -\lambda \nabla g$.

Here is my question: Why does this critical point have to be on the constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the second condition of Lagrange optimality: that the derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t. $\lambda$ has to be equal to zero!
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0$$
This condition implies that, at optimality, $g(x,y)=0$.

Comment: So to get optimality we need $\nabla L(x,y,\lambda) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, the solution is a stationary point with respect to the original variables $x$ and $y$ and the multipliers $\lambda$.